# Valid Date function using <ctime> mktime

Tags: c++, date, mktime, ctime

I wanted a function that would take three inputs of day, month, year and tell me whether it is valid or not. Then using the example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/

I tried to implement my function:

```
bool ValidDate(int d, int m, int y)
{
struct tm *timeinfo;
time_t rawtime;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
timeinfo->tm_year = y - 1900;
timeinfo->tm_mon = m - 1;
timeinfo->tm_mday = d;

if (mktime(timeinfo) == -1 )
    return false;
else return true;
}
```

The problem is that the function is returning not as i want it to.
e.g im checking like

```
if (ValidDate(4,13,2010)) // out put is valid
    std::cout << "valid\n";
else std::cout << "Invalid\n";

ValidDate(4,22,2010) // valid
ValidDate(344,13,2010) //valid
ValidDate(4,133,2010) //valid
ValidDate(31,12, 1920) //invalid
ValidDate(31,9,2010) //valid
ValidDate(4,9,2010) //valid
```

Why? thanks.
EDIT:
all dates entered were invalid except 31,12,1920 and 4,9,2010 and non of the outputs were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) return is as follow :

> Time since epoch as a `std::time_t` object on success or `-1` if time cannot be represented as a `std::time_t` object.

[`std::time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) is defined as follow :

> Arithmetic type capable of representing times.
>
> Although not defined, this is almost always a integral value holding the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since `00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC`, corresponding to [POSIX time](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Unix_time).

So 31/12/1920 cannot be represented into a `std::time_t` as it is before the epoch.

---

As for the other invalid dates that are reported as valid, `mktime` also states :

> The values in [the parameter] are permitted to be outside their normal ranges.

Here is the example taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << "Today is           " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") <<'\n';
    tm.tm_mon -= 100;  // tm_mon is now outside its normal range
    std::mktime(&tm);
    std::cout << "100 months ago was " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z") << '\n';
}
```

Output is :

> `Today is           Wed Dec 28 09:56:10 2011 EST`
>   `100 months ago was Thu Aug 28 10:56:10 2003 EDT`

Comment: No i mean, i entered all invalid dates but almost all were output as valid. And the only valid date as invalid. so what about all others, why were they valid?

Comment: oh, do you mean that this function is only checking the year? so then i cant validate day and month?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider See my edit. It should be clearer now.

Comment: ok, so they are for different things. They allow out of scope variables to increment/decrement dates

Comment: Yes, that makes `mktime` the wrong tool for validating dates.